# How to use Inline jquery in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

This code works perfectly with a href=""> link, but i need jquery inline function to do this, if i click edit(BUTTON) it should update the table details as well as delete. help me out please :(

1.Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function validateForm()
{   
var a=document.forms["emp"]["empid"].value;
    var b=document.forms["emp"]["empname"].value;
    var c=document.forms["emp"]["desig"].value;
    var d=document.forms["emp"]["dept"].value;
    //var e=document.forms["emp"]["skill[]"].checked;
    var empskill = document.forms["emp"]["skill[]"]; 
    /*if((emp.skill[0].checked == false) && (emp.skill[1].checked==false) && (emp.skill[2].checked==false))
    {
        alert("Any one skill must be selected");
        return false;
    }*/
    if(a == null || a == "")
    {
        alert("Employee id must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if(b == null || b == "")
    {
        alert("Employee name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if(c == null || c == "")
    {
        alert("Employee Designation must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if(d == null || d == "")
    {
        alert("Employee department must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if((emp.gender[0].checked==false) && (emp.gender[1].checked==false))
    {
        alert("Please select Any one gender"); return false;
    }
    if( (empskill[0].checked==false) && (empskill[1].checked==false) && (empskill[2].checked==false) )
    {
        alert("Any one skill must be selected"); 
        return false; 
    }

}
function numeric(num)
{   var g=/^[0-9]+$/;
    var h=document.getElementById(num).value;
    if(h.match(g))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Enter numeric values only");
        document.getElementById(num).value=' ';
        return false;
    }
    var az = false;
    for ( var i=0; i<document.forms["emp"]["skill[]"].length; i++ ) {
        var ax = document.forms["emp"]["skill[]"][i].checked;
        az = az || ax;
    }
    console.log(az);    

}
function alphabets(t)
{
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
    var y=document.getElementById(t).value;
    if(y.match(regex)){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Only Alphabetic characters");
        document.getElementById(t).value=' ';
        return false;
    }


}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#74AFAD" >
<center>
<br><br><br><h2>
Employee Master<br><br>
<form method="post" action ="addview.php" name="emp" >
<table border=2 cellpadding=10>
<tr><td>Employee code</td> <td><input type="text" name="empid" id="e_id" oninput="numeric(id)"  ></td></tr>

<tr><td>Employee name</td> <td><input type="text" name="empname" id="e-name" oninput="alphabets(id)"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Designation</td> <td><input type="text" name="desig" id="e_desig" oninput="alphabets(id)"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Department</td> <td><select name="dept">

<option value="">Select department</option>
<option value="sales">Sales</option>
<option value="purchase">Purchase</option>
<option value="production">Production</option></td></tr>

<tr><td>Gender</td> 

<td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" >Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" >Female</td></tr>

<tr><td>Skill </td> <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="sk1"> Sk1
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="sk2"> Sk2
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="sk3"> Sk3</td> </tr>

</table>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" onclick="return validateForm();" >
<input type="submit" name="view" value="View" >

</form> 
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

3.employee.sql(Database)

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.12
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Dec 10, 2015 at 09:44 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.16
-- PHP Version: 5.5.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `employee`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `emp_details`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emp_details` (
  `empid` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `empname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `desig` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dept` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `skill` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `emp_details`
--

INSERT INTO `emp_details` (`empid`, `empname`, `desig`, `dept`, `gender`, `skill`) VALUES
(1, 'Gopi', 'Mg', 'sales', 'male', 'sk1'),
(2, 'Nathan', 'Ceo', 'purchase', 'female', 'sk1'),
(3, 'gows', 'busin', 'sales', 'female', 'sk1');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

2.addview.php

```
<script>
function checkDelete()
{
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
}
</script></head>
<body bgcolor="#74AFAD" >
<?php

$empid=$_POST['empid'];
$empname=$_POST['empname'];
$desig=$_POST['desig'];
$dept=$_POST['dept'];
@$gender=$_POST['gender'];
@$skill=$_POST['skill'];

//$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['empname'];

//echo "Welcome   ".$_SESSION['user']; 

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error connecting to MYSQl");

mysql_select_db("employee",$con);

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
if(isset($_POST['skill']))
{
    $skill=implode(",",$_POST['skill']);
}

$query="insert into emp_details values ('$empid','$empname','$desig','$dept','$gender','$skill')" ;
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
header("location:view.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['view']))
{
$query="select empid,empname,desig,dept,gender,skill from emp_details ORDER BY empid DESC";
$results=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<center><br><br><br><table border=2>";
echo "<th>Employeeid</th><th>Employeename</th><th>Designation</th><th>Department</th><th>Gender</th><th>Skill</th><th>Action</th>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>".$row['empid']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['empname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['desig']. "</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['dept']. "</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['gender']. "</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['skill']. "</td>";
?>
<td><a href='update.php?empid="<?php echo $row['empid'];?>"' value="Edit">Edit</td> 
<td><a href='del.php?empid="<?php echo $row['empid'];?>"' onclick="return checkDelete()">Delete</td></tr>
<?php
}

}
if(isset($_POST['edit']))
{
    header("location:update.php");
}
?>
```

3.update.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
include("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $empid=$_POST['empid'];
        echo $empid;

    $empname=$_POST['empname'];
    $desig=$_POST['desig'];
    $dept=$_POST['dept'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $skill=$_POST['skill'];
    if(isset($_POST['skill']))
{
    $skill=implode(",",$_POST['skill']);
}

    $query="update emp_details set empname='$empname', desig='$desig', dept='$dept', gender='$gender', skill='$skill' where empid='$empid'";
    mysql_query($query);
    header("location:index.php");
}

?>
```

4. Delete.php

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery 'onclick' function to trigger submission on clicking the button.
Then use the jquery ajaxform to submit the form asynchronously to the server side php script
You'll have to use the jqueryform.js to use ajaxform jquery.

Comment: I dont  know how to use jquery.

Comment: You can refer these links   http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form